# Show header always in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, header

I need to show ListView header always, even when ListView has no items.

It is possible to do? Or better add header in ListView as first item?

Comment: Why dont you just put one TextView over your listview in your XML only?

Comment: Header is big, I need to scroll it with listview together.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Irrespective of whether your `ListView` has elements or not, header will be visible always. If there are elements in ListView, header will scroll along with them else it will be on top always.

For how to add header view to ListView, you can refer other answers provided by users.

Comment: You are right, header is visible always. I set empty view and header both and when list view had no items, empty view displays instead of header. Now I remove empty view and all works!

Comment: But how diaplay empty view and header both?

Comment: I don't think u can display both because adding header or footer view is like adding children's itself to listView so emptyView wont display. If thr is any way to do it, sorry am not aware of it. As your header view is big enough, empty view should not b a problem

Comment: THis just isn't right.  Looking at code right now-  it has 0 elements in its adapter.  The header is not shown.

Comment: Agree with @GabeSechan ! This answer is misleading. In my case no header is shown when it has 0 elements.

Comment: On Kitkat (at least), list headers added with `addHeaderView()` aren't visible on an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

If there's no elements for list and you are not adding the adapter, just add this:

```
mListView.setAdapter(null);
```

and the header will appear.

Comment: Note that this breaks the ability for your list to automatically update (e.g. if items are added to the content provider that your adapter is watching)

Comment: Yes, this solution is for a specific cases. I used it in case of "no content downloaded error" where I still want to show the header. In case of "retry" I reload the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity in onCreate You can add header by adding code:

```
View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.header_view, null, false);
        getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
```

In most cases no need to add header, You can just add items in xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

As case you can use http://viewpagerindicator.com/
and set `getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);`  // when your listView has no items

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to manually toggle the empty view.

```
/**
 * Custom empty view handling because we don't want the
 * list to be hidden when the empty view is displayed,
 * since the list must always display the header.
 */
private void toggleEmptyView(Adapter adapter)
{
    final View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            emptyView.setVisibility(adapter.getCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```